# How to know who is changing database data in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Some changes made in my database which is in server how to know who changes the data and what changes they made?

Comment: please add the log if you get an error,

Comment: I suggest you start with changing username and password, and not sharing them with anyone. Connection strings, if provided in configuration, should be encrypted.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it is possible in MySQL but in Oracle you can create system triggers to check who has logged in, which values have been changed etc.

I recommend you to surf in the MySQL triggers website and see if there's something that you need.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html

Comment: It is possible in MySQL but can be a fiddle to set up unless you know what you're doing

Comment: Yeah, might be the case, thing is that the other possible answer is to change username/password and check for logs to see what changes have been made.